# Shortest Path With Linear Time

Tags: graph-theory, algorithms

Given a directed graph $G =(V,E)$, a source Vertex $s \in V$, weight function $w: E \to R^+$ (it is a weighted graph), and a function $d:V \to R^+$. Is there any linear algorithm to check : $\forall v \in V$ if $d(v) = \delta(s,v)$ where $\delta$ is the cost (in weight) from $s$ to $v$.

How can a solution have a linear time $O(V+E)$? The only way I see to solve this problem is to use Dijkstra algorithm (which is not linear of course).

Comment: Linear in terms of what ?

Comment: @YvesDaoust O(n)

Comment: Haha, what is $n$ ?

Comment: @YvesDaoust sorry, in terms of O(V+E)

Comment: Google Breadth-First Search (BFS) that runs in linear time and that is basically your answer.

Comment: Wait a second, I may need to walk my previous comment back, I am not positive BFS runs in linear time on graphs with a length function on the set of edges

Answer (score -1):

A list of algorithms for shortest path problem for directed graphs with nonnegative weights is provided in the [respective section](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shortest_path_problem#Directed_graphs_with_nonnegative_weights) of Wikipedia page.